# How to draw graphs of functions?

Tags: graphing-functions

I have knowledge in programming language C++..However I want to draw graphs of various functions such as $\sin\dfrac{1}{x},x\sin\dfrac{1}{x}$ etc.

Is there any available software that can be run on Windows $7$ for download for plotting these functions

Or can I use C to run programs for plotting them?

I searched on the web ;alternatives are available for Linux etc.

Please do tell me any other alternatives available for windows $7$ operating system

Comment: Matlab,python,mathematica

Comment: Microsoft Mathematics. Free, powerful, easy.

Comment: gnuplot is free.

Comment: You might want to try out the free online service http://www.fooplot.com

Comment: Or even [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org), which is free.

Comment: [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/), free online services like [SageMathCloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/), [SymPy Gamma](http://www.sympygamma.com/)

Comment: [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) uses C++ - like language
to create high-quality 2D and 3D technical drawing, using (La)TeX to handle text labels.
It's also free, open-source.

Comment: Definitely gnuplot. Incredibly easy, open source, and everybody uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desmos,Wolfram Alpha,gnuplot ,Geogebra,Microsoft Mathematics,Matlab,FooPlot,GraphSketch,MAFA Function Plotter.